# Are there any legal or tax issues for an international student receiving a gift via wire transfer?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, money-transfer, f1-student-visa

I am an international student in the USA. I have a friend in UAE, he wants to send me money to cover my tuition cost ~$2500.00. He is planning to send it through the Western Union or Money gram. Do I have any legal issues or limit to receive money as F-1 student. I couldn't find that information under FAQ.
Also, does it consider as an income for me for the Tax purposes?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there shouldn't be a limit on the amount you can receive as a gift, and gifts are not considered income to you; they are not taxable for the recipient.  Depending on the size of the wire transfer, it may be reported by the bank to the government, but there is no limit, and it should not be a concern to you.  (I don't think that $2500 is large enough to be reportable anyway.)

Having said that, this might be a good question to ask your international student advisor at your school to make sure he or she agrees.

There is a very similar question on Avvo.com (a legal question-and-answer site) that agrees:

[Limit to transfer money to students on f1 visa.](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/limit-to-transfer-money-to-students-on-f1-visa--2017766.html)

Comment: If you are a US resident (it can happen in F-1 if you study more than 5 years) , there is a Form 3520 filing requirement when the gift is more than $100,000 from a foreign individual. Also, in my experience advisers never answer specific tax and/or legal questions.